# Install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 from live USB in Lenovo IdeaPad 330

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, live-usb, lenovo, windows-10

I have created a live USB of Ubuntu 18.04 from my already installed Windows 10 software Rufus.

1. I restart my laptop. When the Lenovo logo appears, I press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. My laptop enters the BIOS setup utility.
2. In BIOS menu, I press <kbd>→</kbd> for the required number of times to move to the *Boot* tab.
3. There, my default UEFI is selected. By pressing <kbd>↓</kbd> for the required number of times, I move to Ubuntu Disk option shown under sub-tab of BOOT from. Then I pressed <kbd>F6</kbd> (without <kbd>Fn</kbd>) one time. The *Ubuntu Disk* option moves to the top and *Windows 10 Boot Manager* moves to the second position.
4. Then I press <kbd>F10</kbd> with the label *Save and Exit*. It makes the laptop to save the current configuration of BIOS setup utility and restart.
5. Now when the laptop reboots and the Lenovo logo appears, the laptop boots into Windows 10 mode.

**Why is this happening and how can I accomplish my task?**

I don't want to keep Windows 10 and I want to remove it completely. I only want to keep Ubuntu.

My Lenovo model is Lenovo IdeaPad 330.

This is a screenshot of my Ubuntu 18.04 live USB folder:

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 live USB folder]

If I select Legacy instead of UEFI under the *Boot* tab of the BIOS setup utility, the laptop is able to boot from the Ubuntu live USB, but in the start page, where I have to select language, and then either *Try Ubuntu* or *Install Ubuntu* option only my keyboard is working and the touchpad is not working.

Also if I select the *Try Ubuntu* option, the Ubuntu desktop appears, but there too only my keyboard keys are working and touchpad isn't working.

In legacy mode when the laptop boots from the Ubuntu live USB the following screen appears:

[image: Ubuntu installer Welcome screen]

There is no option of <kbd>f6</kbd> present there. Also the screen is completely different.

After following instructions from the comments, I entered the grub menu, but my grub menu looks different as shown below.

[image: grub menu]

Also there is no `ro quite splash`. There is only `quite splash - -`. I replaced it with `nomodset quite splash`. Then I pressed <kbd>f10</kbd>.

The laptop rebooted from the live Ubuntu USB into *Try Ubuntu*, but still my TouchPad was not working.

Comment: The BIOS is skipping the Ubuntu Disk option at the top and going down to the Windows 10 Boot Manager 2nd option instead. Some BIOSs have not one but two options for USB flash drives in the Boot priority menu of the BIOS. One option is for UEFI USB and the other option is for Legacy or non-UEFI USB. Try selecting the other USB option (if there is one) in the BIOS Boot priority menu.

Comment: But if I wish UEFI, can I do it? Or legacy is compulsory?

Comment: The UEFI option is the way I always do it. I only tried booting from Legacy once to see if it worked and ran the Ubuntu USB as a live session only without installing anything. Then I rebooted and installed Ubuntu with the UEFI option. You can also switch from BIOS mode to UEFI mode after you installed Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix/952952#952952.

Comment: Are you confident that converting into UEFI will not fail and I not have to do a re-installation?

Answer (score 1):

The BIOS is skipping the Ubuntu Disk option at the top and going down to the Windows 10 Boot Manager 2nd option instead. Some BIOSs have not one but two options for USB flash drives in the Boot priority menu of the BIOS. One option is for UEFI USB and the other option is for Legacy or non-UEFI USB. Try selecting the other USB option (if there is one) in the BIOS Boot priority menu. You can also switch from BIOS mode to UEFI mode after you installed Ubuntu: [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix/952952#952952). Comment if you need additional help for your specific situation with dual booting Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 on a Lenovo laptop.

Adding the `nomodeset` parameter to the kernel boot options instructs the kernel to not load video drivers and use BIOS mode instead until X is loaded. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657254/ubuntu-stops-loading/657259#657259) has instructions for how to enable the `nomodeset` kernel boot option.

When you get to the Welcome screen that is shown in your question, click the <kbd>Install Ubuntu</kbd> button to start installing Ubuntu 18.04. If you want to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10, select the *Install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 option* when you get to the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer. If you want to erase Windows 10 and install Ubuntu 18.04 (single boot) select the *Erase Windows 10 and install Ubuntu 18.04* option instead.