# Ubuntu 18.04 kernal crash after install

Tags: 18.04, crash

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my lenovo laptop alongside the Windows 10 the laptop came with as a dual boot.

After creating an instal USB and installing everything, I saw a message to reboot my computer to complete the install, afterwards my laptop froze for a couple of minutes and the following image appeared: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXR0j.jpg

What could have happened and what should I do?

Comment: If you've got a late model Lenovo, try Ubuntu 19.10. Also make sure you've got the latest BIOS. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Are there any known bugs with recent Lenovo models (which my laptop is), and 18.04 or something?

Comment: 19.10 supports newer hardware... but you also need to check your BIOS version.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1101040/install-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows-10-from-live-usb-in-lenovo-ideapad-330

Comment: Which Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ISO did you download & try to install?  Does it contain HWE (hardware enablement stack; which lets it use later kernels & software-stack required for newer hardware) or the original 18.04 without it?   HWE is found on 18.04.2 and later ISO's  (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

Comment: Ok, so I finally managed to solve the problem, there were some driver issues since I have an NVIDIA graphic card, so I just booted using nomodeset and now it works.

Comment: But that just completely disables the Nvidia drivers. What model Nvidia and what version driver?