# Error in Try Ubuntu without installing in Acer Aspire laptop

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, acer

I am trying to `Try Ubuntu without installing` from a USB.
The endless log of the error is above, but I do not understand what is bad.
So, please, someone understand?

```
[ 1520.040015] Hardware name: ACer ASpire A315-41/Metapod_RR, BIOS V4.11 10/30/2018
[ 1520.040015] RIP: 0010:multi_cpu_stop+0x4e/0x100
[ 1520.040015] RSP: 0018:ffffb86580d7be60 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX fffffffffffff
[ 1520.040015] RAX: ... RBX: ... RCX: ...
[ 1520.040015] RDX: ... RSI: ... RDI: ...
[ 1520.040015] RBP: ... R08: ... R09: ...
[ 1520.040015] R10: ... R11: ... R12: ...
[ 1520.040015] R13: ... R14: ... R15: ...
[ 1520.040015] FS: ...  GS: ...  KnIGS: ...
[ 1520.040015] CS: ...  DS: ...  ES: ... CR0 ...
[ 1520.040015] CR2: ... CR3: ... CR4: ...
[ 1520.040015] Call Trace:
[ 1520.040015] ? cpu_stopper_thread+0x110/0x110
[ 1520.040015] cou_stopper_thread+0x97/0x110
[ 1520.040015] smpboot_thread_fn+0xfc/0x170
[ 1520.040015] kthread+0x121/0x140
[ 1520.040015] ? sort_range+0x30/0x30
[ 1520.040015] ? kthread_create_worker_on_cpu+0x70/0x70
[ 1520.040015] ret_from_fork+0x22/0x40
[ 1520.040015] code: ... [large hexadecimal number that change every 10 seconds] ...
```

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU7Rj.jpg)

My laptop is an Acer Aspire3 A315
AMD Ryzen5. I already have a S.O Windows 10, and I want to install in a dual boot the Ubuntu.

Comment: Could this be a hardware problem (like RAM modules that are not seated properly, or an overclocked CPU), or does the system run another OS without complaints?

Comment: yes @Jos, the idea is to install Ubuntu 18.04 as a second S.O. the principal S.O. is Windows and works perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu stops loading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657254/ubuntu-stops-loading)